# How to update table if date has passed?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

On my page I want to display some dates. A script needs to check if the date is in the past or in the future. If it's in the future, the date needs to be displayed. If it's in the past, I want a query to change the value of this date  to "closed", so it won't be displayed any more.

What I have tried:

```
 $deDatum = strtotime($row_originele_datum['datum']); //the date that has to be checked
 $vandaag = strtotime($datum_vandaag); //today's date
 $dataID = $rows_data['id']; //the message ID
 if ($deDatum < $vandaag) {

 $result_sluit_datum = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE belangrijkeDatum SET status = 'gesloten' WHERE id=$dataID");

 }
```

but this seems to do nothing at all. No changes were  made after running the page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
$result_sluit_datum = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE belangrijkeDatum SET status = 'gesloten' WHERE id=$dataID");
```

to

```
$result_sluit_datum = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE belangrijkeDatum SET status = 'gesloten' WHERE id='".$dataID."'");
```

Essentially you are passing $dataID to your query instead of the value of $dataID.

Comment: thanks, that looked logic, still no changes were made after using your code

Comment: never mind. I feel pretty stupid right now. `belangrijkeDatum` had to be `belangrijkeData`, that's why nothing happened. Such a stupid mistake... I had to apply your line in order to make it work anyway, so you did help me after all. Therefor I need to thank you though! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help.  We all have days like that.